# Behavior of ALT in Qt5 applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, qt

I work in Arch Linux 64bit with both English and Hebrew keyboard layouts available, using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change between them.

I recently noticed that when I work in Texmaker, which is a Qt5 application, when I try to switch the language it will do it, but the Texmaker will ignore the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and just treat the <kbd>Alt</kbd> as if I'm going to choose a top menu shortcut next.

Texmaker has a Windows version as well, which I use sometimes, and that's not happening there. But at the same time, in my Firefox, and other text editing software which are all Gtk based, this doesn't happen.

So I decided to ask the developer of Texmaker if something was changed recently, and the answer was negative. Then I decided to install some other Qt5 application which has a top menu, and text input, and much to my dismay the same behavior repeated itself, showing that this is indeed a Qt5 issue.

Is there any way to correct this? I can't say exactly when this happened (I didn't have to type Hebrew into Texmaker for quite some time until now), so it's hard to pinpoint the fault on some particular update or another.

I should perhaps add that I'm using Openbox with SLiM, and have only a few KDE packages installed.

Comment: Since there's no reply here. I'm going to delete my account. Feel free to close and delete this question. Goodbye.